# How do I get html-snapshots to work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, installation, npm

**I'm just trying to run [html-snapshots](https://npmjs.org/package/html-snapshots). This should be easy, right?**

This is what I started with:

```
npm install html-snapshots
```

That's all I need, right? Here's my snapshots.js file:

```
var htmlSnapshots = require('html-snapshots');
htmlSnapshots.run({
    source: "sitemap.xml",
    hostname: "localhost",
    outputDir: "snapshots",
    outputDirClean: true,
    selector: "#results-widget"
});
```

And to run it:

```
node snapshots.js
```

But nooo:

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module '.\robots'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.module.exports.create (C:\webdev\node_modules\html-snapshots\lib\input-generators\index.js:38:16)
    at Object.module.exports.run (C:\webdev\node_modules\html-snapshots\lib\html-snapshots.js:42:39)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\webdev\snapshots.js:2:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
```

wtf?

### Additional Info...

This is part of html-snapshots.js:

```
var inputFactory = require("./input-generators");
...
run: function(options, listener) {
    ...
    var inputGenerator = inputFactory.create(options.input);
    ...
    result = inputGenerator.run(options, (function(options, notifier){
```

Also, the `html-snapshots\lib\input-generators` folder contains the file `robots.js`

Comment: Is that error coming from the library? Perhaps it's missing some dependencies. Check and see what `inputGenerator` is and if it's `required` by something

Comment: Thank you @Houseman, you made me realize that installing robots was the wrong thing to do. There is a robots.js in the input-generators folder that is not being loaded for some reason. (not that I've solved my problem)

Comment: If you really want to thank me, you can upvote my comment. :)

Comment: @GilBirman, What version of `html-snapshots` do you use? I've checked version "0.2.1" and statement which throws an error `var inputGenerator = inputFactory.create(options.input);` is in line 42 (not 43 as in your error). So you may use older version or `html-snapshots\lib\html-snapshots.js` has been amended. I would suggest deleting entire `html-snapshots` directory from `node_modules`, downloading it again with `npm` and applying the fix I provided. You should not get the second error again.

Comment: Thank you Tom. That eliminated the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like an issue inside `html-snapshots\lib\input-generators\index.js` file - it works fine on Linux systems but fails on Windows (`path.sep` has been used to build module name)

Problem is that it should load `'./robots'` module instead of `'.\robots'`.

Quick fix is to update `html-snapshots\lib\input-generators\index.js` file - line 38.

Change line:

```
result = require(file);
```

to:

```
result = require(path.join(__dirname, file));
```

And it will work fine. I hope that will help.

Comment: thanks. new error now. I updated the question with the new error at the bottom.